# PayPal is Truncating My Return Query String

Tags: php, paypal

When connecting to PayPal I use a URL like this (I am using fake values here, but the structure is real):

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?&business=ZDS346347&cmd=_xclick&amount=100&item_name=Test&no_note=1&no_shipping=1&rm=2&return=http://www.website.com/registration.php?paypal=1&classid=122&sessionid=264&studentid=2286

The problem is when I send this url, it truncates my return value query string from this:

```
paypal=1&classid=122&sessionid=264&studentid=2286
```

to this:

```
paypal=1
```

The ampersands in the return value are confusing it, but I need to use them so I can process those query string values on the return.

Is there someway, I can pass that whole return string to PayPal so it won't truncate after the first ampersand it hits.

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the passed URL with [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) to turn the ampersands into PayPal-parsable characters, then when your URL gets called use [`urldecode`](http://php.net/urldecode) to decode them.

This happens because PayPal's URL simply splits everything after the `?` into chunks by the `&` symbol.  It doesn't know when one is part of your website or not.  So it's sending PayPal `classid=122` as it's own key/value pair, not as a part of your URL.  Encoding the URL this way should make it work correctly.

**edit** Referenced the wrong PHP functions.  urlencode/decode are for GET parameter passing, htmlspecialchars is for *storing* HTML data

Comment: I can see how I could use htmlspecialchars to make the string not get broken up by PayPal, but then when PayPal sends my customer back, it won't send it back to the correct string - it will send it back to the string with the special characters.  At that point, it would be to late to decode it - or am I missing something?

Comment: See edit! Meant URLENCODE! PayPal _may_ call the callback URL correctly automatically.  I'm honestly not 100% sure, but I would test that first.  I doubt you need to do more work.  If it doesn't work, that would mean your `$_GET` would have one big string in it with the first parameter only (in your example, `paypal` which is equal to everything else).  Simply get that messy string, decode it and explode, like so: `$gets = explode('&', urldecode($_GET['paypal']));`  Now you can treat `$gets` as if it were `$_GET`, set correctly.  Though, again, I suspect PayPal will callback correctly.